# На какую часть слова стоит ставить ударение во фразе "отзыв лицензии у банка"?

Tags: орфоэпия

Как понимаю, корректно ставить ударение на букву "ы", так как в данном контексте слово означает "отзывать, отозвать"
Но преподаватель по банковскому делу пояснила, что в банковской среде уместно использовать ударение на букву "о". Так же я посмотрела два каких-то ролика на ютубе по банковскому делу, где также было произнесено "Отзыв лицензии".

Answer (score 2):

Вы всё понимаете правильно — ударение падает на последний слог по указанным Вами причинам. Это объясняется во всех толковых, орфографических и орфоэпических словарях. Но если в профессиональной среде распространилось и утвердилось ошибочное произношение, бороться с этим в одиночку будет сложно. Не исключено, что в будущем придётся смириться и Вам, и даже филологам (не редки примеры, когда со временем филологи уступают под давлением профессионального узуса даже в вопросах орфографии — не только орфоэпии).

Comment: Добавлю в комментарии, что много раз слышал выражения типа "отзыв посла", "отзыв судебного иска" и т.п. Кажется, во всех без исключения случаях ударение было неправильным.

Comment: Возможно, словарная двухвариантность ударения в этом слове - не более чем теоретическая рекомендация, с целью отнести варианты к разным порождающим глаголам (отзываться и отзывать). Стихийно же ударение тяготеет в обоих случях к первому слогу, оставаясь _одновариантным_ - как и в словах, близких по форме (отрыв, отклик, откуп и т. п.). "Отзыв" я почти всегда слышу с ударением на первом слоге, и это не кажется жаргонизмом, поскольку из контекста смысл всегда ясен.